# JavaFX set title to be removed on the left side

Tags: javafx, label, vbox, hbox

My problem is described in the picture below. I just want to set the label to be "..."-ed on the left side and not on the right since this is the more important part. As of the code I could show you how I set my label (but that shouldn't really matter):

```
final Label directory = new Label();

directory.setText(selectedDirectory.getPath());
```

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
directory.setStyle("-fx-text-overrun: leading-ellipsis;");
```

or, in an external style sheet:

```
.label {
    -fx-text-overrun: leading-ellipsis ;
}
```